# What is the design number of this brick?

Tags: part-identification, creator

Attached is a picture of one of the bricks from the Dinosaur Set [31058](https://www.lego.com/de-de/product/mighty-dinosaurs-31058). It is however not listed in the content list on lego.com, so I have not been able to find a replacement.

[image: Photo of Brick]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [98613c01 - Hero Factory Arm / Leg Extender with Ball Joint and Ball Socket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98613c01#T=C) on BrickLink.

LEGO call this item [Ball Cup High Friction W. Rubber](https://brickset.com/parts/design-74261) and use 74261 (design ID) and 6106472 (Element number) for latest sets.

LEGO doesn't always have full list of parts within a set as this depends on parts availability (maybe some other reasons too). You would get much better set inventory on BrickLink. Check your set - [31058 on BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=31058-1), where you can find the part you are looking to identify.